# 5.3.3 date() function parsing/formatting incorrectly

Tags: php, date, strtotime

On my website using PHP 5.3.3 the following code is not returning the expected result;

```
echo strtotime('1994-07-04T23:00:00.000Z');
// 773362800 in 5.3.3 and 5.5 ALL GOOD

echo date('d M Y', strtotime('1994-07-04T23:00:00.000Z'));
// OR
echo date('d M Y', 773362800);

// both return 05 July 1994 on my server running 5.3.3, 5.5 returns 04 July 1994
// NOT SO GOOD! It should be 04 July 1994
```

[**Online Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wfKh6i)

I can *fix* the problem by using

```
stristr('1994-07-04T23:00:00.000Z', 'T', true)
```

however there are other bits of code that use dates in the same format. So making this change is not ideal, I'd rather get to the bottom of why the original code is not returning the right date.

Comment: Not sure on the problem, but I would advice you to use **Datetime**-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you showed is a time in UTC. `date()` will use your server's timezone. Assuming that your servers is in a UTC+XXXX timezone, it would be the `5th` of july, not the `4th` anymore.

Comment: Why does the timezone have anything to do with this? Is there any way to force `strtotime()` to ignore the timezone...I don't get why it would take that date string and consider that as a different day :\

Comment: Using the `Z` at the end, you explicitly specified that the time should be in UTC. `strtotime()` gives you a UNIX timestamp for that UTC time. Then you pass that to `date()` which will format UNIX timestamps using the server's timezone. (check the date() manual). PHP does it correct

Comment: @Novocaine Correct (in your case!) would be `echo date('d M Y', strtotime('1994-07-04T23:00:00.000 Europe/London'));`